# Nginx error page configuration "Sorry, Page Not Found"

Tags: nginx

I've setup an Nginx reverse proxy with error page configuration as below:

```
error_page 405 /405.html;
error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 401 400 402 403 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 420 422 423 424 426 428 429 431 444 449 450 451 /40x.html;
error_page 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 /50x.html;
```

However in some cases, Ive still can see the error below "Sorry, Page Not Found":

[image]

Did I missing a configuration?`

Ive search for all html and Nginx source and none of the message "Sorry, Page Not Found" exist.

Nginx Version: 
nginx-1.12.2